# Remove a SMS from my outbox

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung

It happens to me something very annoying ... I sent an pro SMS by mistake to the wrong customer ... I realized it instantly, so I removed my battery immediately and restarted my phone (Samsung galaxy S4 ) without the SIM card.

The SMS was still not send (with the spinning loader), then I got a message like "the sms has not been sent, it will be as soon as you have access to your network".

I manually deleted the message on the page of the conversation, but I think it must be in the outbox. How to be sure it will not be sent when I put my SIM card back? Is there an "outbox" as for mails where I could remove it definitively?

Thank you for your response 
LD